# Display Date Value from BEGIN:VEVENT Raw Data in Android using Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, dateformatter

I am new to android development and I am facing an issue to parse event start and end date to display on UI or activity to text view.

Here is the Raw Data from QR Code.

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:My Event
DESCRIPTION:This the foo event
LOCATION:Location
DTSTART:20200519T142616Z
DTEND:20200527T100000Z
END:VEVENT
```

I am able to parse the raw event date to individual properties under model class. While showing values to the UI that time I wanted to show the date(s) in a readable format.

Now I have the date(s) like below format:

```
String startDate = "20200519T142616Z"; // - What is this Format?
String endDate = "20200527T100000Z";
```

**Question# 1** What types of *"20200519T142616Z"* date Format?

And I wanted to display date(s) like this:

```
Start Date: 05 May 2020 17:26:16
End Date: 27 May 2020 13:00:00
```

I have used the following code snippet that throws exceptions: So how can I parse it?

```
try {
     String property_value = "20200519T142616Z";
     SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:ss:mmZ");
     String startDate = sdf.parse(property_value);
}
catch (ParseException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Question# 2** How to parse *"20200519T142616Z"* date to display format like 05 May 2020 17:26:16?

Please help, I am struggling to find the solution?

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat` is obsolete. See [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

Parse your "basic" [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) string as a [`java.time.OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) object. Generate localized text representing that object’s value via [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class.

```
OffsetDateTime
.parse( 
    "20200519T142616Z" ,
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuuMMdd'T'HHmmssXXXXX" )
)
.format(
    DateTimeFormatter
    .ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.MEDIUM )
    .withLocale( Locale.UK )
)
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/IKxMtK).

> 19 May 2020, 14:26:16

Or, adjust from UTC to a time zone.

```
OffsetDateTime
.parse( 
    "20200519T142616Z" ,
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuuMMdd'T'HHmmssXXXXX" )
)
.atZoneSameInstant(
    ZoneId.of( "Europe/Minsk" ) 
)
.format(
    DateTimeFormatter
    .ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.MEDIUM )
    .withLocale( new Locale( "ru" , "RU" ) )
)
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/IKxMtK).

> 19 мая 2020 г., 17:26:16

Notice how the time-of-day shifted from hour 14 to hour 17. In this example, the time zone `Europe/Minsk` is three hours ahead of UTC. So, 14 + 3 = 17. Same moment, different wall-clock time.

## ISO 8601 “basic” variant

> Question# 1 What types of "20200519T142616Z" date Format?

Your input `"20200519T142616Z"` is formatted using the “basic” variant of a format defined in the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard, minimizing the use of delimiters.

Define a formatting pattern to match your input.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuuMMdd'T'HHmmssXXXXX" ) ;
```

Parse as an [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) object.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( input , f ) ;
```

To see that same moment through the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone), apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( z ) ;
```

Generate localized text representing that zoned date-time. Same moment, same point on the timeline, different wall-clock time.

```
Locale locale = new Locale( "fr" , "TN" ) ;
DateTimeFormatter fOutput = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.LONG ).withLocale( locale ) ;
String output = zdt.format( fOutput ) ;
System.out.println( "output: " + output ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/y4mLiR).

> odt.toString(): 2020-05-19T14:26:16Z
>
> zdt.toString(): 2020-05-19T15:26:16+01:00[Africa/Tunis]
>
> output: 19 mai 2020 à 3:26:16 PM CET

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

## Generate text

> Question# 2 How to parse "20200519T142616Z" date to display format like 05 May 2020 17:26:16?

Not "parse", but "generate", must be what you mean.

To generate text representing the value of our date-time object, use another `DateTimeFormatter` object.

Rather than hard-code a value, let *java.time* localize automatically.

```
Locale locale = Locale.UK ;
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.MEDIUM ).wihLocale( locale ) ;
String output = odt.format( formatter ) ;
```

If the localized text does not suit you, define a formatting pattern as done earlier in the Answer. This has been covered many many times already on Stack Overflow, so search to learn more.

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image]

Comment: Thank you - Basil, for the response, however, I have tried both the solutions provided by you and @brew but no luck. I am wording why we have to include a library for such as small solution? In this case, my application will only work API Level 26+? I am new to Android development I may ask a small question to clear a doubt. 
I can parse the date manually if I am supposed to get only static or known date format, but in my case application can types of Event QR code an example of date format kanzaki.com/docs/ical/dtstart.html#example

Comment: @WmDev Date-time handling is not a "small solution". Date-time is actually a complicated tricky subject area, an area woefully ignored by the IT industry for far too many decades. The *java.time* framework (and its predecessor, *Joda-Time*) is the first serious attempt at a well thought-out knowledgable attempt that I know of. Adding a *ThreeTenABP* library to your early Android project is well worth the bother for almost any amount of date-time work. For Android 26+, no need to add anything. See my revised "About java.time* section.

Comment: @WmDev See my revised code run live at IdeOne.com: https://ideone.com/y4mLiR

Comment: Thank you - Basil, it helps me a lot to understand the concept of various date formats to resolve my problem. However, I have to set my Android application's minSdkVersion 26 (API level 26) then only new API worked. I tried ThreeTenABP Lib also but did not help for the same case scenario.

Comment: @WmDev What was the problem with *ThreeTenABP*? Did you read the page I linked, *How To Use ThreeTenABP*?

Comment: Yes, I followed that link, and implemented as to support as is it for minimum versions of APIs, there are some issues to support Android < 26 then I ended up to use minSdkVersion 26.

Answer (score 0):

**Question# 1** What types of "20200519T142616Z" date Format?

**Answer**:  It is **Zulu** time formate. The “Zulu” comes from military and aviation tradition where 25 letters of the alphabet A-Z (no "J"), each letter having a pronounceable name, represents [their version of time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_military_time_zones). The "Zulu" zone is zero hours offset from UTC. For more check out [link 1](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/z) and [link 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Coordinated_Universal_Time&mobileaction=toggle_view_desktop#Time_zones).

This format is formally defined in the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard.

**Question# 2** How to parse "20200519T142616Z" date to display format like 05 May 2020 17:26:16?

**Answer**: The T is just a literal to separate the date from the time, and the Z means "zero hour offset" also known as "Zulu time" (UTC). If your strings always have a "Z" you can use:

You need to convert this into a standard Format "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.US);
    simpleDateFormat .setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    try {
        //20200519T142616Z // wrong format // this gives exception here
        /*
        * you format this string correctly 
        * after formatting your start date 
        * 2020-05-19T14:26:16.(three digit missing here)Z
        * 20200527T100000Z // wrong format 

        * 2020-05-19T14:17:46.316Z  // correct format
        * OUTPUT: E/test date: Tue May 19 05:30:00 GMT+05:30 2020
        * */
        Log.e("test date ", String.valueOf(format.parse("2020-05-19T14:26.126Z")));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

check for cached Exception [here](https://pastebin.com/9ubu3t1D)
or

you can use [dateTime()](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html#dateTime--)

Comment: You are using terrible legacy date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.